# How does MATLAB connect 3d points?

Tags: matlab, animation, graph, plot, 3d

I want to create a rocket shape by specifying a "cloud" of surface points and making MATLAB connect the points into rectangular patches (such that when there are many of these, it creates the illusion of a curved surface). How can I make MATLAB do this? I.e. in what order must I specify the points in order to make MATLAB patch them together correctly?

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

The above is using plot3; what I have is a long matrix of the following structure:

```
[x1 y1 z1
 x2 y2 z2
 .
 .
 .]
```

I would like to know how to make this into a surface. The full matrix is:

```
   -0.2470    0.0380         0
   -0.2470    0.0374    0.0066
   -0.2470    0.0357    0.0130
   -0.2470    0.0329    0.0190
   -0.2470    0.0291    0.0244
   -0.2470    0.0244    0.0291
   -0.2470    0.0190    0.0329
   -0.2470    0.0130    0.0357
   -0.2470    0.0066    0.0374
   -0.2470    0.0000    0.0380
   -0.2470   -0.0066    0.0374
   -0.2470   -0.0130    0.0357
   -0.2470   -0.0190    0.0329
   -0.2470   -0.0244    0.0291
   -0.2470   -0.0291    0.0244
   -0.2470   -0.0329    0.0190
   -0.2470   -0.0357    0.0130
   -0.2470   -0.0374    0.0066
   -0.2470   -0.0380    0.0000
   -0.2470   -0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.2470   -0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.2470   -0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.2470   -0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.2470   -0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.2470   -0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.2470   -0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.2470   -0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.2470   -0.0000   -0.0380
   -0.2470    0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.2470    0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.2470    0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.2470    0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.2470    0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.2470    0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.2470    0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.2470    0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.1970    0.0380         0
   -0.1970    0.0374    0.0066
   -0.1970    0.0357    0.0130
   -0.1970    0.0329    0.0190
   -0.1970    0.0291    0.0244
   -0.1970    0.0244    0.0291
   -0.1970    0.0190    0.0329
   -0.1970    0.0130    0.0357
   -0.1970    0.0066    0.0374
   -0.1970    0.0000    0.0380
   -0.1970   -0.0066    0.0374
   -0.1970   -0.0130    0.0357
   -0.1970   -0.0190    0.0329
   -0.1970   -0.0244    0.0291
   -0.1970   -0.0291    0.0244
   -0.1970   -0.0329    0.0190
   -0.1970   -0.0357    0.0130
   -0.1970   -0.0374    0.0066
   -0.1970   -0.0380    0.0000
   -0.1970   -0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.1970   -0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.1970   -0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.1970   -0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.1970   -0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.1970   -0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.1970   -0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.1970   -0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.1970   -0.0000   -0.0380
   -0.1970    0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.1970    0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.1970    0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.1970    0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.1970    0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.1970    0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.1970    0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.1970    0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.1470    0.0380         0
   -0.1470    0.0374    0.0066
   -0.1470    0.0357    0.0130
   -0.1470    0.0329    0.0190
   -0.1470    0.0291    0.0244
   -0.1470    0.0244    0.0291
   -0.1470    0.0190    0.0329
   -0.1470    0.0130    0.0357
   -0.1470    0.0066    0.0374
   -0.1470    0.0000    0.0380
   -0.1470   -0.0066    0.0374
   -0.1470   -0.0130    0.0357
   -0.1470   -0.0190    0.0329
   -0.1470   -0.0244    0.0291
   -0.1470   -0.0291    0.0244
   -0.1470   -0.0329    0.0190
   -0.1470   -0.0357    0.0130
   -0.1470   -0.0374    0.0066
   -0.1470   -0.0380    0.0000
   -0.1470   -0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.1470   -0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.1470   -0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.1470   -0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.1470   -0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.1470   -0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.1470   -0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.1470   -0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.1470   -0.0000   -0.0380
   -0.1470    0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.1470    0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.1470    0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.1470    0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.1470    0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.1470    0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.1470    0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.1470    0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.0970    0.0380         0
   -0.0970    0.0374    0.0066
   -0.0970    0.0357    0.0130
   -0.0970    0.0329    0.0190
   -0.0970    0.0291    0.0244
   -0.0970    0.0244    0.0291
   -0.0970    0.0190    0.0329
   -0.0970    0.0130    0.0357
   -0.0970    0.0066    0.0374
   -0.0970    0.0000    0.0380
   -0.0970   -0.0066    0.0374
   -0.0970   -0.0130    0.0357
   -0.0970   -0.0190    0.0329
   -0.0970   -0.0244    0.0291
   -0.0970   -0.0291    0.0244
   -0.0970   -0.0329    0.0190
   -0.0970   -0.0357    0.0130
   -0.0970   -0.0374    0.0066
   -0.0970   -0.0380    0.0000
   -0.0970   -0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.0970   -0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.0970   -0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.0970   -0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.0970   -0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.0970   -0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.0970   -0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.0970   -0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.0970   -0.0000   -0.0380
   -0.0970    0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.0970    0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.0970    0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.0970    0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.0970    0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.0970    0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.0970    0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.0970    0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.0470    0.0380         0
   -0.0470    0.0374    0.0066
   -0.0470    0.0357    0.0130
   -0.0470    0.0329    0.0190
   -0.0470    0.0291    0.0244
   -0.0470    0.0244    0.0291
   -0.0470    0.0190    0.0329
   -0.0470    0.0130    0.0357
   -0.0470    0.0066    0.0374
   -0.0470    0.0000    0.0380
   -0.0470   -0.0066    0.0374
   -0.0470   -0.0130    0.0357
   -0.0470   -0.0190    0.0329
   -0.0470   -0.0244    0.0291
   -0.0470   -0.0291    0.0244
   -0.0470   -0.0329    0.0190
   -0.0470   -0.0357    0.0130
   -0.0470   -0.0374    0.0066
   -0.0470   -0.0380    0.0000
   -0.0470   -0.0374   -0.0066
   -0.0470   -0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.0470   -0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.0470   -0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.0470   -0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.0470   -0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.0470   -0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.0470   -0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.0470   -0.0000   -0.0380
   -0.0470    0.0066   -0.0374
   -0.0470    0.0130   -0.0357
   -0.0470    0.0190   -0.0329
   -0.0470    0.0244   -0.0291
   -0.0470    0.0291   -0.0244
   -0.0470    0.0329   -0.0190
   -0.0470    0.0357   -0.0130
   -0.0470    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.0030    0.0380         0
    0.0030    0.0374    0.0066
    0.0030    0.0357    0.0130
    0.0030    0.0329    0.0190
    0.0030    0.0291    0.0244
    0.0030    0.0244    0.0291
    0.0030    0.0190    0.0329
    0.0030    0.0130    0.0357
    0.0030    0.0066    0.0374
    0.0030    0.0000    0.0380
    0.0030   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.0030   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.0030   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.0030   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.0030   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.0030   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.0030   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.0030   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.0030   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.0030   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.0030   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.0030   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.0030   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.0030   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.0030   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.0030   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.0030   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.0030   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.0030    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.0030    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.0030    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.0030    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.0030    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.0030    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.0030    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.0030    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.0530    0.0380         0
    0.0530    0.0374    0.0066
    0.0530    0.0357    0.0130
    0.0530    0.0329    0.0190
    0.0530    0.0291    0.0244
    0.0530    0.0244    0.0291
    0.0530    0.0190    0.0329
    0.0530    0.0130    0.0357
    0.0530    0.0066    0.0374
    0.0530    0.0000    0.0380
    0.0530   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.0530   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.0530   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.0530   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.0530   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.0530   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.0530   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.0530   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.0530   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.0530   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.0530   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.0530   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.0530   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.0530   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.0530   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.0530   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.0530   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.0530   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.0530    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.0530    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.0530    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.0530    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.0530    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.0530    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.0530    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.0530    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.1030    0.0380         0
    0.1030    0.0374    0.0066
    0.1030    0.0357    0.0130
    0.1030    0.0329    0.0190
    0.1030    0.0291    0.0244
    0.1030    0.0244    0.0291
    0.1030    0.0190    0.0329
    0.1030    0.0130    0.0357
    0.1030    0.0066    0.0374
    0.1030    0.0000    0.0380
    0.1030   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.1030   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.1030   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.1030   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.1030   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.1030   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.1030   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.1030   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.1030   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.1030   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.1030   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.1030   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.1030   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.1030   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.1030   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.1030   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.1030   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.1030   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.1030    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.1030    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.1030    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.1030    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.1030    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.1030    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.1030    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.1030    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.1530    0.0380         0
    0.1530    0.0374    0.0066
    0.1530    0.0357    0.0130
    0.1530    0.0329    0.0190
    0.1530    0.0291    0.0244
    0.1530    0.0244    0.0291
    0.1530    0.0190    0.0329
    0.1530    0.0130    0.0357
    0.1530    0.0066    0.0374
    0.1530    0.0000    0.0380
    0.1530   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.1530   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.1530   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.1530   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.1530   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.1530   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.1530   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.1530   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.1530   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.1530   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.1530   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.1530   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.1530   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.1530   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.1530   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.1530   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.1530   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.1530   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.1530    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.1530    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.1530    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.1530    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.1530    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.1530    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.1530    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.1530    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.2030    0.0380         0
    0.2030    0.0374    0.0066
    0.2030    0.0357    0.0130
    0.2030    0.0329    0.0190
    0.2030    0.0291    0.0244
    0.2030    0.0244    0.0291
    0.2030    0.0190    0.0329
    0.2030    0.0130    0.0357
    0.2030    0.0066    0.0374
    0.2030    0.0000    0.0380
    0.2030   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.2030   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.2030   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.2030   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.2030   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.2030   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.2030   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.2030   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.2030   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.2030   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.2030   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.2030   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.2030   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.2030   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.2030   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.2030   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.2030   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.2030   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.2030    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.2030    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.2030    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.2030    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.2030    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.2030    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.2030    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.2030    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.2530    0.0380         0
    0.2530    0.0374    0.0066
    0.2530    0.0357    0.0130
    0.2530    0.0329    0.0190
    0.2530    0.0291    0.0244
    0.2530    0.0244    0.0291
    0.2530    0.0190    0.0329
    0.2530    0.0130    0.0357
    0.2530    0.0066    0.0374
    0.2530    0.0000    0.0380
    0.2530   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.2530   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.2530   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.2530   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.2530   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.2530   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.2530   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.2530   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.2530   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.2530   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.2530   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.2530   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.2530   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.2530   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.2530   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.2530   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.2530   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.2530   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.2530    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.2530    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.2530    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.2530    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.2530    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.2530    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.2530    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.2530    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.3030    0.0380         0
    0.3030    0.0374    0.0066
    0.3030    0.0357    0.0130
    0.3030    0.0329    0.0190
    0.3030    0.0291    0.0244
    0.3030    0.0244    0.0291
    0.3030    0.0190    0.0329
    0.3030    0.0130    0.0357
    0.3030    0.0066    0.0374
    0.3030    0.0000    0.0380
    0.3030   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.3030   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.3030   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.3030   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.3030   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.3030   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.3030   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.3030   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.3030   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.3030   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.3030   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.3030   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.3030   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.3030   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.3030   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.3030   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.3030   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.3030   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.3030    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.3030    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.3030    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.3030    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.3030    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.3030    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.3030    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.3030    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.3530    0.0380         0
    0.3530    0.0374    0.0066
    0.3530    0.0357    0.0130
    0.3530    0.0329    0.0190
    0.3530    0.0291    0.0244
    0.3530    0.0244    0.0291
    0.3530    0.0190    0.0329
    0.3530    0.0130    0.0357
    0.3530    0.0066    0.0374
    0.3530    0.0000    0.0380
    0.3530   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.3530   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.3530   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.3530   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.3530   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.3530   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.3530   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.3530   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.3530   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.3530   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.3530   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.3530   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.3530   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.3530   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.3530   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.3530   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.3530   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.3530   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.3530    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.3530    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.3530    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.3530    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.3530    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.3530    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.3530    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.3530    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.4030    0.0380         0
    0.4030    0.0374    0.0066
    0.4030    0.0357    0.0130
    0.4030    0.0329    0.0190
    0.4030    0.0291    0.0244
    0.4030    0.0244    0.0291
    0.4030    0.0190    0.0329
    0.4030    0.0130    0.0357
    0.4030    0.0066    0.0374
    0.4030    0.0000    0.0380
    0.4030   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.4030   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.4030   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.4030   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.4030   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.4030   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.4030   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.4030   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.4030   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.4030   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.4030   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.4030   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.4030   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.4030   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.4030   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.4030   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.4030   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.4030   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.4030    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.4030    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.4030    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.4030    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.4030    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.4030    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.4030    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.4030    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.4530    0.0380         0
    0.4530    0.0374    0.0066
    0.4530    0.0357    0.0130
    0.4530    0.0329    0.0190
    0.4530    0.0291    0.0244
    0.4530    0.0244    0.0291
    0.4530    0.0190    0.0329
    0.4530    0.0130    0.0357
    0.4530    0.0066    0.0374
    0.4530    0.0000    0.0380
    0.4530   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.4530   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.4530   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.4530   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.4530   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.4530   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.4530   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.4530   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.4530   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.4530   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.4530   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.4530   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.4530   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.4530   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.4530   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.4530   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.4530   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.4530   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.4530    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.4530    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.4530    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.4530    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.4530    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.4530    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.4530    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.4530    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.5030    0.0380         0
    0.5030    0.0374    0.0066
    0.5030    0.0357    0.0130
    0.5030    0.0329    0.0190
    0.5030    0.0291    0.0244
    0.5030    0.0244    0.0291
    0.5030    0.0190    0.0329
    0.5030    0.0130    0.0357
    0.5030    0.0066    0.0374
    0.5030    0.0000    0.0380
    0.5030   -0.0066    0.0374
    0.5030   -0.0130    0.0357
    0.5030   -0.0190    0.0329
    0.5030   -0.0244    0.0291
    0.5030   -0.0291    0.0244
    0.5030   -0.0329    0.0190
    0.5030   -0.0357    0.0130
    0.5030   -0.0374    0.0066
    0.5030   -0.0380    0.0000
    0.5030   -0.0374   -0.0066
    0.5030   -0.0357   -0.0130
    0.5030   -0.0329   -0.0190
    0.5030   -0.0291   -0.0244
    0.5030   -0.0244   -0.0291
    0.5030   -0.0190   -0.0329
    0.5030   -0.0130   -0.0357
    0.5030   -0.0066   -0.0374
    0.5030   -0.0000   -0.0380
    0.5030    0.0066   -0.0374
    0.5030    0.0130   -0.0357
    0.5030    0.0190   -0.0329
    0.5030    0.0244   -0.0291
    0.5030    0.0291   -0.0244
    0.5030    0.0329   -0.0190
    0.5030    0.0357   -0.0130
    0.5030    0.0374   -0.0066
    0.5530    0.0347         0
    0.5530    0.0342    0.0060
    0.5530    0.0326    0.0119
    0.5530    0.0301    0.0174
    0.5530    0.0266    0.0223
    0.5530    0.0223    0.0266
    0.5530    0.0174    0.0301
    0.5530    0.0119    0.0326
    0.5530    0.0060    0.0342
    0.5530    0.0000    0.0347
    0.5530   -0.0060    0.0342
    0.5530   -0.0119    0.0326
    0.5530   -0.0174    0.0301
    0.5530   -0.0223    0.0266
    0.5530   -0.0266    0.0223
    0.5530   -0.0301    0.0174
    0.5530   -0.0326    0.0119
    0.5530   -0.0342    0.0060
    0.5530   -0.0347    0.0000
    0.5530   -0.0342   -0.0060
    0.5530   -0.0326   -0.0119
    0.5530   -0.0301   -0.0174
    0.5530   -0.0266   -0.0223
    0.5530   -0.0223   -0.0266
    0.5530   -0.0174   -0.0301
    0.5530   -0.0119   -0.0326
    0.5530   -0.0060   -0.0342
    0.5530   -0.0000   -0.0347
    0.5530    0.0060   -0.0342
    0.5530    0.0119   -0.0326
    0.5530    0.0174   -0.0301
    0.5530    0.0223   -0.0266
    0.5530    0.0266   -0.0223
    0.5530    0.0301   -0.0174
    0.5530    0.0326   -0.0119
    0.5530    0.0342   -0.0060
    0.6030    0.0242         0
    0.6030    0.0238    0.0042
    0.6030    0.0227    0.0083
    0.6030    0.0209    0.0121
    0.6030    0.0185    0.0155
    0.6030    0.0155    0.0185
    0.6030    0.0121    0.0209
    0.6030    0.0083    0.0227
    0.6030    0.0042    0.0238
    0.6030    0.0000    0.0242
    0.6030   -0.0042    0.0238
    0.6030   -0.0083    0.0227
    0.6030   -0.0121    0.0209
    0.6030   -0.0155    0.0185
    0.6030   -0.0185    0.0155
    0.6030   -0.0209    0.0121
    0.6030   -0.0227    0.0083
    0.6030   -0.0238    0.0042
    0.6030   -0.0242    0.0000
    0.6030   -0.0238   -0.0042
    0.6030   -0.0227   -0.0083
    0.6030   -0.0209   -0.0121
    0.6030   -0.0185   -0.0155
    0.6030   -0.0155   -0.0185
    0.6030   -0.0121   -0.0209
    0.6030   -0.0083   -0.0227
    0.6030   -0.0042   -0.0238
    0.6030   -0.0000   -0.0242
    0.6030    0.0042   -0.0238
    0.6030    0.0083   -0.0227
    0.6030    0.0121   -0.0209
    0.6030    0.0155   -0.0185
    0.6030    0.0185   -0.0155
    0.6030    0.0209   -0.0121
    0.6030    0.0227   -0.0083
    0.6030    0.0238   -0.0042
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
    0.6530         0         0
```

Comment: Sequentially? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB plots the points in the same order as the vector that you supply.  For example,

```
plot3([x1 x2 x3], [y1 y2 y3], [z1 z2 z3])
```

will connect `[x1 y1 z1]` to `[x2 y2 z2]`, and connect `[x2 y2 z2]` to `[x3 y3 z3]`.  If you want to create a rocket shape that is composed of several curves, then you will need to use one `plot3` command for each curve.